# Не работает адаптив картинки. Как исправить?

Tags: html, css

В данном случае картинке задано, чтоб на устройствах более, чем 540рх, она отображалась на половину ширины экрана(50vw). Но это не работает. Что не так с моим кодом?

```html
<picture>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dtQLbqkK/photo-2020-10-08-12-15-49.jpg 426w" sizes="(min-width: 540px) 50vw">
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/4drQ8YNZ/photo-2020-10-08-12-06-49.jpg 1280w 3x, https://i.postimg.cc/SsWnhRfm/photo-2020-10-08-12-14-56.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 540px) 50vw">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
 <img 
  src="https://i.postimg.cc/dtQLbqkK/photo-2020-10-08-12-15-49.jpg" 
  sizes="(min-width: 540px) 50vw, (max-width: 540px) 100vw"
  srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/4drQ8YNZ/photo-2020-10-08-12-06-49.jpg 1280w, https://i.postimg.cc/SsWnhRfm/photo-2020-10-08-12-14-56.jpg 640w">
```

Comment: Разве для ретина дисплеев можно использовать и w дескриптор тоже. я имею в виду, что для экрана с большей плотностью пикселей браузер выбирает изображение с большим расширением?

Comment: По моему, артрибут  sizes работает только для тех элементов, у кого задан дескриптор w. То бишь, данный дескриптор будет работать только для srcset. Для src что?

Comment: Нет ничего для src. Если вы используете srcset - прописываете там все картинки, и после этого добавляете src, который является "дефолтным" изображением

Comment: понятно, спасибо